# Get a List of All Commenters on the Current Post

Tags: comments

I'm trying to get a list of everyone who's commented on a post, and then check that list against the current logged in user. If the current logged in user is included in that list, then I don't show the comment form, otherwise they can leave a comment. So essentially, I only want people to be able to comment once per post.

I think I'm close, but I keep pulling in a list of everyone who's commented on *any* post.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php global $post;
      $comments = get_comments($post->ID); // get all comment author emails
      foreach($comments as $comment) :
        $existingcommenters = $existingcommenters.', '.$comment->comment_author_email;
      endforeach;

      $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // then we check those emails against the current users email
      $commenting = $current_user->user_email; ?>

<?php $args = array( // i then list my arguments, which I've omitted for clarity here
    ); ?>

<?php if (strpos($existingcommenters,$commenting) !== false) { // if the user already has a review, don't let them post another ?>
    <p>You've already reviewed this business.</p>
<?php } else { comment_form($args); } ?>
```

So I thought `$existingcommenters` should only contain a list of people who've commented on this post, as `$comments = get_comments($post->ID);` should be setting that call to only get a list of comments for this post, right?

If I echo `$post->ID` anywhere in this code, it does return the current post's ID successfully.

But if I echo `$existingcommenters`, it shows a list of every single commenter.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show us the completed code and tell us where it goes/how you got it working? Thanks

Comment: @Pete see my comment in the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_comments` do not get a post ID as parameter but rather an array in which you can set all kinds of query criteira including post ID. See the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments.

You can even use the `author_email` parameter to make `get_comments` do most of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks @mark-kaplun, that lead me to the correct answer, which is changing my second line of code to this: `$comments = get_comments( array ( 'post_id' => get_the_ID() ) );`